# Table of Frequency from file data in python

Tags: python, file, for-loop, graph, nested-for-loop

Currently, my code is looking like this:

```
import re


def get_filename():
    """gets the file from the inputed filename"""
    filename = input("Please enter filename: ")
    return filename
   
    
def get_words_from_file(filename):
    """getting the data from the file and getting it between the two points."""
    infile = open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    outfile = infile.read().splitlines()
    infile.close()
    words = []
    reading = False
    for let in outfile:
        if let.startswith("*** START OF")and reading == False:
            reading = True
        elif let.startswith("*** END OF SYNTHETIC TEST CASE ***") or let.startswith("*** END"):
            return words
        elif reading:
            let = let.lower()
            words.extend(re.findall("[a-z]+[-'][a-z]+|[a-z]+[']?|[a-z]+", let))
    return words


def calculate(words):
    """calculates the summary of the words"""
    all_times = []
    max_word_length = 0
    number_of_words = len(words)
    average = sum(len(word) for word in words) / number_of_words
    for word in words:
        if len(word)>max_word_length:
            max_word_length=len(word)
    frequency = {word: 0 for word in words}
    for word in words:
        frequency[word] += 1
    max_frequency = max(frequency.values())
    
    summary = (number_of_words, average, max_word_length, max_frequency)
    return summary


def get_frequency(words):
    """gets the frequency of the words"""
    len_count = {}
    for line in words:
        for word in line.split():
            word_len = len(word)
            if not word_len in len_count:
                len_count[word_len] = 1
            else:
                len_count[word_len] += 1
    answer = (word_len, len_count)
    return answer


def print_results(stats_tuple, word_frequency):
    """prints the goods"""
    (word_len, len_count) = word_frequency
    (number_of_words, average, max_word_length, max_frequency) = stats_tuple
    print("")
    print("Word summary (all words):")
    print(" Number of words = {0}".format(number_of_words))
    print(" Average word length = {:.2f}".format(average))
    print(" Maximum word length = {0}".format(max_word_length))
    print(" Maximum frequency = {0}".format(max_frequency))
    print("")
    print(" Len  Freq")
    for word_len in range(1, max(len_count) + 1):
        print('{:>4}{:>6}'.format(word_len, len_count.get(word_len, 0)))
    print("")
    print(" Len  Freq Graph")
    for word_len in range(1, max(len_count) + 1):
        relative_freq = int(int(len_count.get(word_len, 0))/ number_of_words*100)
        print('{:>4}{:>5}% {}'.format(word_len,relative_freq,("="*relative_freq)))
    
    
def main():
    """main function which links everything together"""
    filename = get_filename()
    data = get_words_from_file(filename)
    stats = calculate(data)
    word_frequency = get_frequency(data)
    print_results(stats, word_frequency)


main()

Say my data from the file is:
Toby's code was rather "interesting", it had the following issues: short,
meaningless identifiers such as n1 and n; deep, complicated nesting;   
a doc-string drought; very long, rambling and unfocused functions; not 
enough spacing between functions; inconsistent spacing before and 
after operators, just like   this      here. Boy was he going to get a low
style mark.... Let's hope he asks his friend Bob to help him bring his code
up to an acceptable level.
```

I then have to print out a table that looks like this:

```
% frequency
 30
 29
 28
 27
 26
 25
 24
 23
 22
 21
 20           **
 19           **  **
 18           **  **
 17           **  **
 16           **  **
 15           **  **
 14           **  **
 13           **  **
 12       **  **  **
 11       **  **  **
 10       **  **  **
  9       **  **  **  **
  8       **  **  **  **  **
  7       **  **  **  **  **
  6       **  **  **  **  **  **      **
  5   **  **  **  **  **  **  **      **      **
  4   **  **  **  **  **  **  **      **      **
  3   **  **  **  **  **  **  **      **      **
  2   **  **  **  **  **  **  **      **  **  **
  1   **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **
      01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  10  11  12
                                         word length
```

That table uses the formatting guide of:

- The y-axis labels should be right aligned numbers in a field width of
  3, followed by two spaces. The y-axis labels should go from 1 through
  to the next multiple of 10 above the maximum relative frequency, eg,
  if the maximum relative frequency is 24% the y-axis should be from 1
  to 30, if the maximum relative frequency is 40% then the y-axis
  should go from 1 to 50.
- The x-axis should run from 01 through to the longest word length.
- The x-axis label line should start with five spaces and then be
  followed by two digit numbers (with a leading zero). The numbers
  should have a space (' ') before and after each number.
- The bars should be two *'s with a space either side.
- The label on the y-axis should simple be '% frequency' and be printed
  at the margin.
- The label for the x-axis is 'word length' and should be right-aligned
  so that it finishes in line with the last digit of the last word
  length but with the constraint that it must be preceded by at least 5
  spaces.
- White space at the end of lines is acceptable.

Here's my thinking, I have to make a new function that uses a nested for loop to get the counts of each point on the graph, from there I don't really know what to do. It would be amazing if someone could please help me.